# Troubleshooting API call and MUI table return

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, material-ui

I am trying to get this list of members from a Postgres table on the backend and return and display in an MUI table element in React on the front end.

The API is working and returning the appropriate data, I can see it logged as an array on the front end. However no rows except the header display in the MUI table.

See the React code here:

service:

```
import {IBrother} from "../interfaces/api.interface";

const a = require('axios');

const axios = a.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
});

export async function getAllBrothers(): Promise<Array<IBrother>> {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/brothers');
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

table component:

```
import {Paper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow} from "@mui/material";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {getAllBrothers} from "../../services/brotherService";
import {IBrother} from "../../interfaces/api.interface";

export default function BrotherTableComponent() {

    let rows: Array<IBrother> = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        const getBrothers = () => {
            getAllBrothers().then(response => {
                response.map(row => {
                    console.log(row);
                    rows.push(row);
                })
            })
        }

        getBrothers();
        console.log(rows);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="Brothers' Table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Last Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">First Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Email</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Phone</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Pledge Class</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Graduation</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Office</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Status</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                        <TableRow
                            key={row.id}
                            sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                        >
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {row.last_name}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.first_name}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.email}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.phone}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.pledge_class}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.graduation}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.office}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{row.status}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    )
}
```

Tried various combinations of JSON parsing, etc. On the back end the response is being send as JSON... I just think I am missing something in the formatting of the array since all the content is there, but there appears to be no rows iterated by the map function.